# make an urgent dag run skip the queue

Tags: airflow

I am creating many DagRuns that some are in queue (we are using the default celery queue executor). we are looking for an option. that we can create a new DagRun that will get a higher priority and will be the next one to be run and practically bypass all the next dag runs that are waiting in the queue (sort of an "urgent" run). So we are looking for a way to prioritize DagRuns and not Operators/Tasks. We couldnt find anything that does that.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is to reduce the `default_pool` to a number that is less than the maximum number of tasks.

Ex: For the CeleryExecutor Airflow runs a maximum of 16 tasks concurrently.
You can reduce `default_pool` to 15.

Then you should create `priority_pool` with a limit of 5 (just a random number between 1 and 15) and assign it for prioritized DAGRuns.

That way you will always have a free slot for your priority tasks that will not affect too much your default tasks. I know that this is not exactly what you wanted but, as far as I know, Airflow doesn't have an opportunity to prioritize DAGRuns, only Tasks are possible.